# hover not working with other div elements

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover

This is all the style on that button and i want to make the click and apply to be hidden and when mouse is hovered the text appears just on hover and vanish when mouse is taken off

Html Code

```
  <section class="call-to-action">         
    <h1>Enroll for various online courses<br>Anywhere from the world</h1>
    <div class="click">Click</div> <div class="apply"> to Apply </div> 
    <a href="#">Call to Action</a>  
  </section>
```

Css Code

```
.call-to-action a
{
color: white;                              
text-decoration: none;                          
font-weight: bolder;                   
letter-spacing: 2px;                        
display: inline-block;                               
background: transparent;                               
padding: 20px 14px;                               
border: .9px solid beige;                               
cursor: pointer;                               
transition: 0.7s;                                
 }
                           
.call-to-action a:hover
{
color: white;                               
text-decoration: none;                               
font-weight: bolder;                               
display: inline-block;                               
background: rgb(221, 64, 53);                               
padding: 20px 14px;                               
border: 1px solid beige;                               
cursor: pointer;                               
transition: 0.7s ;                               
transform:scale(1.2,1.2);                               
}
                           
.call-to-action .click
{
opacity: 0;                               
color: black;                               
font-size:20px ;                                                               
}
                           
.call-to-action .apply 
 {
  opacity: 0;                               
  color: black;                               
 font-size:20px ;                               
 }
                                                                                         
 .call-to-action a:hover > .click                               
 {                                                              
color: white;                               
position: absolute;                               
transform: translate(-40%,-40%);                               
font-size: 300px;                               
transition: 0.4s;                               
opacity: 1;                                  
 }
```

Can anyone help me in this situation

Comment: The selector `.call-to-action a:hover > .click` will not work because you cannot select "backwards"/"upwards" in CSS. Your popup-text element has to be a child element of the one you are toggling.

Comment: i have tried with .call-to-action a:hover .click 
that also did not worked

Comment: in order to apply hover effect ".click" should be child of "a" as already stated by @lupz

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this method:

**What happening here?**

By default the opacity of click and apply text are 0.So its not visible to user. While you hovering on the text we change the opacity to 100% with trasition of 0.3second duration. So the text will be visible to use by a small fade-in animation.

**Check the CSS code below**

```css
.call-to-action .click,
.call-to-action .apply{
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #000;
  /* other syles you need */
}
.call-to-action .click:hover,
.call-to-action .apply:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.call-to-action a
{
color: white;                              
text-decoration: none;                          
font-weight: bolder;                   
letter-spacing: 2px;                        
display: inline-block;                               
background: transparent;                               
padding: 20px 14px;                               
border: .9px solid beige;                               
cursor: pointer;                               
transition: 0.7s;                                
 }
                           
.call-to-action a:hover
{
color: white;                               
text-decoration: none;                               
font-weight: bolder;                               
display: inline-block;                               
background: rgb(221, 64, 53);                               
padding: 20px 14px;                               
border: 1px solid beige;                               
cursor: pointer;                               
transition: 0.7s ;                               
transform:scale(1.2,1.2);                               
}
                           
.call-to-action .click
{
opacity: 0;                               
color: black;                               
font-size:20px ;                                                               
}
                           
.call-to-action .apply 
 {
  opacity: 0;                               
  color: black;                               
 font-size:20px ;                               
 }
                                                                                         
 .call-to-action a:hover > .click                               
 {                                                              
color: white;                               
position: absolute;                               
transform: translate(-40%,-40%);                               
font-size: 300px;                               
transition: 0.4s;                               
opacity: 1;                                  
 }
 
.call-to-action .click, .call-to-action .apply{
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  opacity: 0;
  color: #000000;
}
.call-to-action .click:hover, .call-to-action .apply:hover{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<section class="call-to-action">         
    <h1>Enroll for various online courses<br>Anywhere from the world</h1>
    <div class="click">Click</div> <div class="apply"> to Apply </div> 
    <a href="#">Call to Action</a>  
  </section>
```

Comment: i just wanted that if i hover the button the text ----apply to click---- should come above the button with applied css and if remove the mouse from button the text should dissappears

Answer (score 0):

The CSS rules are applied from top to bottom and from parent to children.

You can't do CSS selections upwards or backwards to apply properties to a parent or earlier sibling element.

But you can wrap both elements within a container element to apply your styles.

```css
.button-tooltip-container .tooltip {
    opacity: 0;                                                              
}
.button-tooltip-container:hover .tooltip {
    opacity: 1;                                                              
}
```

```html
<div class="button-tooltip-container">
    <div class="tooltip">Button tooltip text</div>
    <button>Call to Action</button>
</div>
```

You should read this in order to get started with CSS selectors https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors

Comment: i did not get you
my css is already in the same parent element and but just i am trying access another child element from a child inside a parent one

Comment: There is no such hierarchy in CSS. The HTML markup defines what is parent and what is children. Hence, it defines how and what you can select.